# Control brightness of 20 watt street LED light using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-due, arduino-nano

I have searched google and I now know that if we change the resistance, we can change the brightness of an LED, but I was wondering how to change resistance by using a micro controller.

Comment: Normally you use PWM instead of messing with resistances. It's easier and more efficient.

Comment: There are I2C controlled resistors. But I know none that can handle 20W. Most likely a SSR (Solid State Relay) and PWM'ing would work but I don't know how good idea that is.

Comment: High power leds don't use resistors, but have special drivers that regulate the voltage going into the led. With streetlights these drivers also handle the AC-to-DC conversion. It's unlikely you can dim these externally.

Comment: There are LED drivers that have external regulation options but as OP asked about changing resistance with a microcontroller the answer would be with a I2C pot, but it's unsuitable for dimming a 20W LED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do a web search? "[arduino pwm high power led driver](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=arduino%20pwm%20high%20power%20led%20driver)" gives all the info you may need to answer this.

Here is a nice youtube clip, by [Julian Ilett](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmHvGf00GDuPYG9DZqQKd9A) that explains how to do this: [60W High Power LED Driver with PWM #2 - Brightness Control](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7CA1brVXDA).

Comment: Mikael, this is basically a link-only answer. Can you expand on it a bit please in case the link goes down?

Comment: The video is by Julian Ilett, who has a rather large collection of tutorials on YouTube, so hopefully the link won't go down.